# How to pass a parameter between UWP pages when navigation is initiated from a parent page?

Tags: c#, parameters, uwp, navigation, parameter-passing

I am using a navigation model that has a MainPage, which contains a hamburger menu and a MyFrame in a splitview. I have two pages, WorkingPage and SavePage, which are displayed in the MyFrame. So MainPage includes this:

```
<Page>
    <!-- Other stuff -->

    <SplitView>
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <!-- Other stuff -->

            <ListBox Name="HamburgerMenuMenuItems"
                     SelectionChanged="HamburgerMenuMenuItems_SelectionChanged">

                    <ListBoxItem Name="HamburgerMenuItemSave">
                        <!-- Content -- >
                    </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>

            <!-- Other stuff -->
        </SplitView.Pane>

        <SplitView.Content>
            <Frame Name="MyFrame"></Frame>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>

    <!-- Other stuff -->
</Page>
```

The user clicks Save, which is one of the items in the Hamburger menu (set up as a listbox), and which raises the selection changed event, on the MainPage, which results in MainPage initiating a navigation from WorkingPage to SavePage in MyFrame.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private void HamburgerMenuMenuItems_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Other options similar ...
        else if (HamburgerMenuItemSave.IsSelected)
        {
            MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Pages.File.SavePage));
        }
        // Other options similar ...
    }
}
```

WorkingPage contains a data member that I want SavePage to have access to.

This is what I have:

```
public sealed partial class WorkingPage : Page
{
    public MyClass myClass;
    // Other stuff ...
}
```

I want the value of "myClass" to be passed to SavePage, so it ultimately ends up as:

```
public sealed partial class SavePage : Page
{
    public MyClass myClass;
    // Other stuff ...
}
```

I know from research (and extensively using it myself) that the proper way to pass parameters between two pages is as follows:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageClass), someParameter);
```

But the problem is MainPage is where the navigation is initiated, but the needed parameter value to pass (myClass) only exists in the scope of WorkingPage. This thus requires that either:

- A) the navigation be initiated by WorkingPage, so that I can use the line of code above, and just put in "SavePage" as the PageClass and "myClass" as the parameter, or
- B) MainPage somehow needs to obtain knowledge of the value of "myClass", so that I can use the same line of code as (A), but with "this.MyFrame" instead of "Frame"

How can getting the value of "myClass" from WorkingPage to SavePage be accomplished, with a navigate event initiated from MainPage? This seems like a common need, but everything I have found only talks about the simple case of one page initiating navigation to another, when a parameter must be passed from the initiating page to the other.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this can be done in different ways.. but personally I like to use following pattern to achieve this :

Firstly, in your `MainPage` you have to create sort of an *utility* method for the navigation  :

```
public void navigateWithParameter(Page yourPage,String yourParameter){
 MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(yourPage), yourParameter);
}
```

Next you can call this method from *any page* you want to (which in your case is the `WorkingPage`), by getting the **current instance** of the `MainPage` and calling the `navigateWithParameter` function with the appropriate parameters :

```
var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
var mainpage = (MainPage)frame.Content;
mainpage.navigateWithParameter(yourPage,"It works!");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Using a utility method like that is actually a really cool idea! The part that still needs to be addressed, though, is that the event (and thus handler) is taking place on MainPage, but the parameter for yourParameter is on the WorkingPage. I could call the utility function from MainPage, but it has no knowledge of the parameter that needs to be passed.

Comment: The utility function is in the `MainPage` which can be called **from the WorkingPage** or any other page (which has the knowledge of the parameter).. You are passing "It works!" (as the parameter here) and specifying which page the `MyFrame`(which is located in the `MainPage`) should navigate to. I will edit my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Through further research, I found a way to address this issue (other ways may exist). There exists a property of a Frame that allows you to get a reference to the page the frame is currently displaying:

```
MyFrame.Content
```

Thus, on MainPage, in the event handler, you can obtain a reference to the page being displayed, which then allows you to access MyClass, since it is a public data member. You can then pass the value of MyClass into the page being navigated to... all without WorkingPage having any knowledge of the event firing.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private void HamburgerMenuMenuItems_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Other options similar ...
        else if (HamburgerMenuItemSave.IsSelected)
        {
            // 1. Check if the current page is the correct type
            if (MyFrame.Content is WorkingPage workingPage)
            {
                // 2. Grab the data to pass from the instance of the displayed page
                MyClass dataToPass = workingPage.myClass;

                // 3. Pass the grabbed data to the page being navigated to
                MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Pages.File.SavePage), dataToPass);
            }
        }
        // Other options similar ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task. I have a UWP page with a lot of settings, grouped buttons with binded NumberBoxes. To move out of `MainPage` all button handlers needed a "helper Class". There I passed the main page object, which automaticaly gives me access to all elements in my `MainPage`.

My `XAML` looked like is:

```
<Page> <Grid>
    <StackPanel  >
        <muxc:NumberBox x:Name="Offset" PlaceholderText="0,35"  />
        <Button Content="GrOffset" Click="buttonClickHandler.Offset_Click"   /> 
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="Messager_Container" Text="Total" />

<Grid/>
<Page/>
```

C# is

```
namespace Eval
      {
            public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
            {   /// <summary>
                /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
                /// </summary>
      
                ButtonClickHandler buttonClickHandler = new ButtonClickHandler();    // create a new instance of our "helper class"
         //===================================    
                public MainPage()
                { 
                        this.InitializeComponent();
                        var mainPageVAR = this; // only for check ot, is it valid assigning
                        buttonClickHandler.mainPage = this; //assign to, we pass the addres to our MainPage class instance
                }
                public class ButtonClickHandler  // our helping class
                {
                    public Eval.MainPage mainPage;
               
                    public void Offset_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                    {     
                        mainPage.Messager_Container.Text= 
                        mainPage.Offset.Value.ToString();
    // our value from numberBox "Offset" passed to TextBox "Messager_Container"
                    }
               }
        }
```